# Find the Physical Offset Number of the Swapfile

Tags: swap, hibernate

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a new device and I'm trying to enable hibernation. I followed the instruction from (https://linuxhint.com/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-22-04-lts/) but I'm stuck at the step of finding "the Physical Offset Number of the Swapfile". I tried the suggested command

```
sudo filefrag -v /dev/sda7 | head --lines=10
```

where /dev/sda7 is the location of my swap partition but I'm getting

```
Filesystem type is: 1021994
File size of /dev/sda7 is 0 (0 blocks of 4096 bytes)
/dev/sda7: 0 extents found
```

so I cannot find that physical offset number.

Comment: Seems youre using a swap partition, not a swap file. You will not be able to find the offset of an non-existing file. If you use a swap partition, just UUID should be sufficient, offset is only needed for a swap file.

Comment: That worked, thank you!